# Create another window of same class in PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I am creating a small GUI program using PySide. I am having difficulty creating another object of same class. What exactly I am trying to do is that when clicked on a button on MainWindow it should create another independent window of same class.

```
import sys 
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui 

class Sticky(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ....
        self.addToolBarElements()
        ....
        self.show()

    def addToolBarElements(self):
        ....
        self.newwindow = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'icons/new.png')),"New Note",self)
        self.newwindow.setStatusTip("New")
        self.newwindow.triggered.connect(newwindow)

        self.toolBar.addAction(self.newwindow)

    def newwindow(self):
        #how to create new object of same class

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    notes = Sticky()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is what I have tried:

I have tried multiprocessing but I didn't understand much. I tried calling run() method again but it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call with the same name 2 different elements, in your case `self.newwindow` refers to the `QAction` as the method of the class, avoid it, that is a type of error easy to commit but difficult to find.

going to the point, you just have to create a new object of the class, but the problem is that the garbage collector will eliminate it, to avoid it there are 2 possible options, the first is to make the new window member of the class, or second store it in a list, that's the one I choose because I think you want to have several windows.

```
import sys 
import os

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui 

class Sticky(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.others_windows = []
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.addToolBarElements()
        self.show()

    def addToolBarElements(self):
        self.toolBar = self.addToolBar("toolBar")
        self.newwindow = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'icons/new.png')), "New Note",self)
        self.newwindow.setStatusTip("New")
        self.newwindow.triggered.connect(self.on_newwindow)

        self.toolBar.addAction(self.newwindow)

    def on_newwindow(self):
        w = Sticky()
        w.show()
        self.others_windows.append(w)

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    notes = Sticky()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

run()
```

Comment: Thank you, So much. It worked like a charm. Wasn't aware about this.